After upgrading .NET 8.0 ef core migrations failed
After adding new migration, it gives an error in ContextModelSnapshot file :'OwnedNavigationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'HasDiscriminator' and no accessible extension method 'HasDiscriminator' accepting a first argument of type 'OwnedNavigationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This was happening to us as well after a migration to EF 8. We narrowed it down to a class hierarchy issue. E.g. we have a Loan class that has a collection of RefundableCharge objects and RefundableCharge inherits from some other class, Charge. When we changed RefundableCharge so that it didn't inherit (and copied the properties over from Charge), the error went away. I.e. the migration doesn't include the .HasDiscriminator call anymore.
Not sure why this is and the base class is small enough that this isn't a huge faux pas, design-wise. But I'm going to investigate a bit more to see if I can fix this a bit more cleanly
